# Question about a continuity result by P. A. Raviart

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde

I am trying to prove the Remark (Remarque) 1.1 in a paper by P.A. Raviart published in 1970 about parabolic equations with a nonlinearity in the time derivative. The remark, where no computations are provided, recites:

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $T>0$ be given, let $1< \alpha <2$, and let $u \in L^\infty(0,T;L^\alpha(\Omega))$ be such that:
$$
\dfrac{d}{d t}\left(|u|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u\right) \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega)).
$$

Then, we have that $\left(|u|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2} u\right) \in \mathcal{C}^0([0,T];L^2(\Omega))$ and that $u\in\mathcal{C}^0([0,T];L^\alpha(\Omega))$.

**My attempt**

(i) $\left(|u|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2} u\right) \in \mathcal{C}^0([0,T];L^2(\Omega))$.

To see this, observe that:
$$
\int_{0}^{T} \int_{\Omega} \left||u|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u\right|^2 d x d t= \int_{0}^{T} \int_{\Omega} |u|^\alpha d x d t.
$$

Since it was assumed that $u \in L^\infty(0,T;L^\alpha(\Omega))$, then the latter integral is finite. Hence, combining the latter with the assumption on the distributional derivative in time gives
$$
\left(|u|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u\right) \in H^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega)) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{C}^0([0,T];L^2(\Omega)).
$$

This completes the proof of (i).

(ii) An auxiliary result. Let $\alpha>1$. Then
$$
|x-y|^\alpha \le \left||x|^\alpha - |y|^\alpha\right|, \quad\mbox{ for all } x,y \ge 0.
$$

To show the auxiliary result assume, without loss of generality, that $x \ge y > 0$, and let
$$
t:=\dfrac{x}{y} \ge 1.
$$

Therefore, the sought inequality is equivalent to proving that
$$
(t-1)^\alpha \le t^\alpha -1,\quad\mbox{ for all }t \ge 1.
$$

Consider the function $f:[1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f(t):=(t-1)^\alpha-t^\alpha+1.
$$

Observe that
$$
f'(t)=\alpha (t-1)^{\alpha-1}-\alpha t^{\alpha-1}=\alpha((t-1)^{\alpha-1}-t^{\alpha-1}).
$$

Since $\alpha-1>0$ and since $0\le t-1 <t$, the monotonicity of the power operator gives that $(t-1)^{\alpha-1} \le t^{\alpha-1}$, so that $f'(t)\le 0$ for all $t>1$. Since $f(1)=0$, we infer that $f(t)\le 0$ for all $t \ge 1$ and the proof of (ii) is complete.

(iii) $|u|\in\mathcal{C}^0([0,T];L^\alpha(\Omega))$.

We have to show that for each $t_0 \in [0,T]$,
$$
\lim_{t\to t_0} \int_{\Omega} ||u(t)|-|u(t_0)||^\alpha d x =0.
$$

By part (ii), we have that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the triangle inequality give
\begin{align*}
&\int_{\Omega} ||u(t)|-|u(t_0)||^\alpha d x \le \int_{\Omega} \left||u(t)|^\alpha-|u(t_0)|^\alpha\right| d x\\
&=\int_{\Omega}\left|\left|\left||u(t)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t)\right|^{2/\alpha}\right|^\alpha-\left|\left||u(t_0)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t_0)\right|^{2/\alpha}\right|^\alpha\right| d x
=\int_{\Omega}\left|\left||u(t)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t)\right|^2-\left||u(t_0)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t_0)\right|^2\right| d x\\
&=\int_{\Omega} \left|\left(\left||u(t)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t)\right|-\left||u(t_0)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t_0)\right|\right) \cdot \left(\left||u(t)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t)\right|+\left||u(t_0)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t_0)\right|\right)\right| d x\\
&\le \left\|\left||u(t)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t)\right|-\left||u(t_0)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t_0)\right|\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
\left\|\left||u(t)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t)\right|+\left||u(t_0)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t_0)\right|\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\\
&\le \left\||u(t)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t)-|u(t_0)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t_0)\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
\left\|\left||u(t)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t)\right|+\left||u(t_0)|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u(t_0)\right|\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)}.
\end{align*}

Observe that the continuity in $[0,T]$ of $\left(|u|^\frac{\alpha-2}{2}u\right)$ implies the uniform boundedness of the second factor, as well as that the first factor tends to zero as $t \to t_0$.
This completes the proof of (iii).

Now, I don't know how to go on. I observe that the conclusion is true if the target space  $L^\alpha(\Omega)$ is replaced by $\mathbb{R}$. I cannot see how to extend the argument to the vector-valued case.

Could you please help me?

Comment: On the set $\{t \in [0,T]: u(t) \neq 0 \}$, you are fine, as $u = \frac{|u|^{(\alpha-2)/2}u}{|u|^{(\alpha-2)}}$ is a quotient of continuous functions with non-zero denominator. For $t_2 \in \{t \in [0,T]: u(t) = 0 \}$, $|u(t) - u(t_2)|_\alpha = |u(t)|_\alpha$, the continuity result is given in your part (iii).

Comment: Sorry for the typo: in the first case, $u = \frac{ |u|^{(\alpha-2)/2} u }{|u|^{(\alpha-2)/2}}$.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. Your argument works if the target space is $\mathbb{R}$. I do not think that the same argument works in Bochner spaces. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Let $f$ be a continuous scalar function on $[0,T]$, and $v \in C([0,T];X)$, where $X$ is a Banach space. Then $fv:[0,T] \to X, fv(t):= f(t) v(t)$ is continuous.

Comment: I don't think the composition you proposed is feasible. I think I have found a way to solve the issue using a classical result. I will post the answer in the coming days.

Comment: Why not? You could always scale a vector in a Banach space.